# misinterpreting echo = false using Rstudio in an rmarkdown file / codechunk

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a fairly basic question. Let's say I have the following code block in an rmarkdown file, that does nothing but resets my global environment, loads in several libraries, and includes 1 print statement.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
rm(list = ls())

# data manipulation
library(jsonlite); library(plyr); library(dplyr); library(data.table); 

# data scraping
library(RSelenium); library(rvest); library(XML); 

# parallel computing / faster code
library(foreach); library(doParallel); library(microbenchmark); 

print("this")

# machine learning
library(rpart.plot); library(glmnet); library(rpart); library(gbm); 
library(nnet); library(caret); library(randomForest); 

# lineup optimization
library(lpSolve);  

# data visualization
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2);
```
````

when I run this, i get the following output in the console

```
> rm(list = ls())
> 
> # data manipulation
> library(jsonlite); library(plyr); library(dplyr); library(data.table); 
> 
> # data scraping
> library(RSelenium); library(rvest); library(XML); 
> 
> # parallel computing / faster code
> library(foreach); library(doParallel); library(microbenchmark); 
> 
> print("this")
[1] "this"
> 
> # machine learning
> library(rpart.plot); library(glmnet); library(rpart); library(gbm); 
> library(nnet); library(caret); library(randomForest); 
>  
> # lineup optimization
> library(lpSolve);  
> 
> # data visualization
> library(ggplot2); library(reshape2);
```

however, I thought the purpose of setting echo = false was that everything besides [1] "this" was supposed to be suppressed in the console, which is what I would like. What is setting echo = FALSE actually doing? And what do I actually have to do to to suppress the repetition of code in the console? The rest of my code has important print statements that confirm my code is operating correctly, but it is being drowned out in the console by the code repetition.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you want `include=FALSE`

Comment: thanks, but didn't do the trick. neither did message = FALSE down below.

Answer (score 3):

*Note that chunk options only affect the display of output when knitting. Sourcing code independent of knitting would require a different approach.*

When you load packages, what you're seeing most of the time are messages, not source code. So to suppress things like `## Attaching package: 'dplyr' ...`, you have to also add the option `message = FALSE`, so the chunk instructions would be `{r , echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}` to suppress both message and source code in the knit document.

Comment: I want to suppress everything besides errors and print statements. including message = FALSE and include = FALSE didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @Canovice are you running the code in the console or knitting the Rmarkdown file?

Comment: I am running code in Rstudio / in the console on a mac using cmd shift enter to run code chunks.

Comment: @canovice the knit chunk options only affect output when you knit, not when you source as you are doing. Try cmd shift s for source without echo

Comment: cmd shift s appears to do better, in that it suppresses repeating code in the console, however this runs the entire document not just rmd code chucks

Comment: there are chunk options http://yihui.name/knitr/options/ in the top right corner of the chunk in rstudio, but none of these toggles are working for me the way I want them to

Comment: Yeah, the reason is the knitr options are all designed to work on the output when you knit, not when running specific chunks. The chunk options gear in the top right corner of each chunk are an R Studio addon for convenience

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it so more, it sounds like the goal is not to knit.  One way to get at that would be to put all of the content you want to suppress the messages / output for (and which you know will work reliably) into a separate .R file and source it.  Another way would be to go full-package and set the libraries as dependencies, but that's more work.

Comment: yeah i don't want to knit, and would prefer to avoid sourcing files. just want to run my chunks without the console repeating all of the code. but it sounds like this might not be possible with the current options in rstudio

Answer (score 1):

`Knitr` is not designed to alter what's displayed in the console. The R console and history keep a perfect, verbatim copy of all commands and output and, as far as I know, there's no way to alter this behaviour. I strongly advise you shouldn't try to change it either, because imagine you ran some analyses and forgot to run a code chunk: you'd have no audit trail of your commands to check against.

`Knitr` is designed to create documents (html, docx, or pdf for the most part) and changing chunk options such as `echo` affects what is displayed in the resulting document, *not* the console. How to control output is well documented on the knitr webpage: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/

Having established that we're not going to get exactly what you want, here are a few options that might help you separate code from output:

## Use `ctrl/cmd + L`

This simply clears the console, so you can step through, clear what you don't need, and run sections of code with results. This requires a lot of manual intervention though; not recommended.

## Use `sink()`

`sink()` allows you to save output to a text file, so the flow of your `.R` script might look something like:

```
...    
# parallel computing / faster code
library(foreach); library(doParallel); library(microbenchmark); 

sink(file = "test.txt")
print("this")
sink()

# machine learning
library(rpart.plot); library(glmnet); library(rpart); library(gbm); 
library(nnet); library(caret); library(randomForest);

sink(file = "test.txt", append = TRUE)
print("that")
sink()
...
```

The contents of `test.txt` now looks like this:

```
[1] "this"
[1] "that"
```

*Don't* forget the **`append = TRUE`** otherwise the contents will get overwritten which is probably not what you want.

`sink()` works, but there are easier and more elegant solutions now...

## Use `knitr` (as it was intended)

I use `knitr` all the time for precisely the reason you're looking for a solution, namely to separate execution code from results.

Separate out your chunks and the following example (when knit!) will get you a document along the lines of what you're looking for:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Canovice"
date: "22 December 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE
)
```

```{r}
# rm(list = ls())
# you don't need this
# by default, each time you knit, knitr uses a clean session

# data manipulation
library(jsonlite); library(plyr); library(dplyr); library(data.table)

# data scraping
library(RSelenium); library(rvest); library(XML)

# parallel computing / faster code
library(foreach); library(doParallel); library(microbenchmark)
```

```{r}
print("this")
```

```{r}
# machine learning
library(rpart.plot); library(glmnet); library(rpart); library(gbm); 
library(nnet); library(caret); library(randomForest); 

# lineup optimization
library(lpSolve);  

# data visualization
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
```
````

The resulting document just displays the result of the code:

> test
>
> Canovice
>
> 22 December 2016
>
> `## [1] "this"`

## Use R Notebook

In RStudio versions > 1.0 you can use the new R Notebook format which works the same way as Rmarkdown knitr documents, except there's a handy button which allows you to display or hide code as you wish.

Have a look at this for example: https://rpubs.com/pssguy/220641

At the top of the page, and for each individual section, there is an option to show or hide the code and just leave the result.